# Memory allocation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, heap-memory, automatic-ref-counting

In swift, based on Apple's documentation reference types are stored on heap and value types on stack, but if a class definition has a struct variable for example String, where will that be stored?

```
class ABC {
  var str: String
  init() {
    self.str = ""
  }
}
```

Where will be str stored?